make_geocube : cannot convert float infinity to integer (when I change CRS it works)
I have this geodataframe, incremenents_raster, that I wanted to rasterize :
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
frame_id 2017-01-01 2017-01-16 2017-02-01 2017-02-16 2017-03-01 
0 122516 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
1 122517 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
2 122518 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
2017-03-16 2017-04-01 2017-04-16 2017-05-01 ...  2023-08-16 
0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...         0.0
1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...         0.0
2 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ...         0.0
2023-09-01 2023-09-16 2023-10-01 2023-10-16 2023-11-01 2023-11-16 
0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
1 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
2 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
2023-12-01 2023-12-16 geometry
0 0.0 0.0 POLYGON ((2842481.248 9119200.259, 2841481.248...
1 0.0 0.0 POLYGON ((2842481.248 9120200.259, 2841481.248...
2 0.0 0.0 POLYGON ((2842481.248 9121200.259, 2841481.248...
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[3 rows x 170 columns]
The crs of this geodataframe is 5880.
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(increments_raster, geometry='geometry', crs='EPSG:5880')
out_grid = make_geocube(
    vector_data=gdf,
    resolution=(1000.0,1000.0),
    measurements=list(date_cols),
    geom=am_bounds.geometry.item(),
    fill=0.0,
    output_crs='EPSG:5880')

And I get the following error :
{
    "name": "OverflowError",
    "message": "cannot convert float infinity to integer",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
File <timed exec>:4

File ~/anaconda3/envs/GEOSPATIAL2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/geocube/api/core.py:99, in make_geocube(vector_data, measurements, datetime_measurements, output_crs, resolution, align, geom, like, fill, group_by, interpolate_na_method, categorical_enums, rasterize_function)
     35 \"\"\"
     36 Rasterize vector data into an ``xarray`` object.  Each attribute will be a data
     37 variable in the :class:`xarray.Dataset`.
   (...)
     95 
     96 \"\"\"
     97 geobox_maker = GeoBoxMaker(output_crs, resolution, align, geom, like)
---> 99 return VectorToCube(
    100     vector_data=vector_data,
    101     geobox_maker=geobox_maker,
    102     fill=fill,
    103     categorical_enums=categorical_enums,
    104     measurements=measurements,
    105     group_by=group_by,
    106     datetime_measurements=datetime_measurements,
    107 ).make_geocube(
    108     interpolate_na_method=interpolate_na_method,
    109     rasterize_function=rasterize_function,
    110 )

File ~/anaconda3/envs/GEOSPATIAL2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/geocube/vector_to_cube.py:104, in VectorToCube.__init__(self, vector_data, geobox_maker, fill, categorical_enums, measurements, datetime_measurements, group_by)
    100     load_measurements.append(self._group_by)
    101 self._vector_data = load_vector_data(
    102     vector_data, measurements=load_measurements
    103 )
--> 104 self._geobox = geobox_maker.from_vector(self._vector_data)
    105 self._grid_coords = affine_to_coords(
    106     self._geobox.affine, self._geobox.width, self._geobox.height
    107 )
    108 if self._geobox.crs is not None:

File ~/anaconda3/envs/GEOSPATIAL2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/geocube/geo_utils/geobox.py:202, in GeoBoxMaker.from_vector(self, vector_data)
    200     geom_crs = CRS(crs_input)
    201     geopoly = Geometry(self.geom, crs=geom_crs)
--> 202 return GeoBox.from_geopolygon(geopoly, self.resolution, crs, self.align)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/GEOSPATIAL2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/odc/geo/geobox.py:677, in GeoBox.from_geopolygon(geopolygon, resolution, crs, align, shape, tight, anchor, tol)
    674 else:
    675     geopolygon = geopolygon.to_crs(crs)
--> 677 return GeoBox.from_bbox(
    678     geopolygon.boundingbox,
    679     crs,
    680     shape=shape,
    681     resolution=resolution,
    682     anchor=anchor,
    683     tol=tol,
    684     tight=tight,
    685 )

File ~/anaconda3/envs/GEOSPATIAL2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/odc/geo/geobox.py:590, in GeoBox.from_bbox(bbox, crs, tight, shape, resolution, anchor, tol)
    588     offy, ny = snap_grid(bbox.bottom, bbox.top, ry, None, tol=tol)
    589 else:
--> 590     offx, nx = snap_grid(bbox.left, bbox.right, rx, _snap.x, tol=tol)
    591     offy, ny = snap_grid(bbox.bottom, bbox.top, ry, _snap.y, tol=tol)
    593 affine = Affine.translation(offx, offy) * Affine.scale(rx, ry)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/GEOSPATIAL2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/odc/geo/math.py:274, in snap_grid(x0, x1, res, off_pix, tol)
    271     return x1, max(nx, 1)
    273 off = off_pix * abs(res)
--> 274 _tx, nx = _snap_edge(x0 - off, x1 - off, res, tol)
    275 return _tx + off, nx

File ~/anaconda3/envs/GEOSPATIAL2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/odc/geo/math.py:242, in _snap_edge(x0, x1, res, tol)
    240 assert x1 >= x0
    241 if res > 0:
--> 242     return _snap_edge_pos(x0, x1, res, tol)
    243 _tx, nx = _snap_edge_pos(x0, x1, -res, tol)
    244 tx = _tx + nx * (-res)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/GEOSPATIAL2/lib/python3.12/site-packages/odc/geo/math.py:233, in _snap_edge_pos(x0, x1, res, tol)
    231 assert res > 0
    232 assert x1 >= x0
--> 233 _x0 = floor(maybe_int(x0 / res, tol))
    234 _x1 = ceil(maybe_int(x1 / res, tol))
    235 nx = max(1, _x1 - _x0)

***OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer"***
}

What I do not understand is that if I perform this operation with change the coordinates to crs = 4674, this error does not appear... and as a result the raster file is created for me.
Unfortunately, I cannot use crs = 4674 since the raster image that I will have to create will have to have 1km x 1km as its size, and since this crs takes into account latitude and longitude as you know, the further I move away from the equator, the more approximate the measurements are. This problem on the other hand with crs = 5880 does not appear, since 1km x 1km will be accurate in every corner of the world.
Can anyone point me to a solution?

EPSG:5880 will not be accurate to the "corners of the world", it will be quiet accurate to the corners of Brazil. What are the bounds of your dataset?

Hi Ian, thank you for answering me. I forgot to say that i am working with the brazilian's amazonas (DETER). My bounds are : (min_x = 2.794481e+06, min_y = 8.004200e+06, max_x = 6.110767e+06, max_y = 1.058642e+07) from the am_bound GeoDataframe ( is the shape of all the interest area used to process the increments_raster). So EPSG:5880 should not be a problem... right ?
